# rendered not working in Primefaces5+JSF2

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Here my XHTML code

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="selectone"
                    value="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.tweetType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group Tweets" itemValue="GT" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Event Tweets" itemValue="ET" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suprachar Tweets" itemValue="ST" />
                    <p:ajax event="click"
                        listener="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.renderUploadPanel}"
                        update="gtid" process="@form" />
                </p:selectOneRadio>
```

and Java method i am calling

```
public void renderUploadPanel(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
       // String selecteValues = (String) event. ;
        visibleGTFlag = true;
        System.out.println("Method called----------->"+visibleGTFlag);
    }
```

And i want to rendred this panel when a checkbox is clicked

```
<p:panel id="gtid"
                rendered="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.visibleGTFlag}"
                toggleable="true">
                <p:fileUpload
                    fileUploadListener="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.handleFileUpload}"
                    mode="advanced" multiple="true" update="messages" auto="true"
                    sizeLimit="1048576" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/" />
            </p:panel>
```

But when i am refreshing this page then this panel rendering what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the scope of your bean? If is `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped`, what's the initial value of `visibleGTFlag` field?

Comment: I am using `@SessionScoped`

Comment: When you say you refresh the page you actually refresh the whole page or you're referring to the ajax update?

Comment: Yes that what i am saying when i am clicking check-box it should be work bot it is not working it is working when i am manually refreshing whole page as boolean value true it showing panel its a issue it should be show panel when i am clicking on checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when a component has `rendered="false"` it won't be added in the view tree component, so it cannot be referenced nor updated by any component in the current view. This explains why this update fails when you try to update the component by an ajax request, because you're still in the same view, while when you fire a complete request on the page you can see the component, because it is a new view.

The solution for these problems is to wrap the non-rendered component inside a UIContainer and update the wrapper component instead. You may use `<h:panelGroup layout="block">` that will render as a HTML div:

```html
<p:selectOneRadio id="selectone"
    value="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.tweetType}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Group Tweets" itemValue="GT" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Event Tweets" itemValue="ET" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Suprachar Tweets" itemValue="ST" />
    <p:ajax event="click"
        listener="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.renderUploadPanel}"
        update="gtidWrapper" process="@form" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<!-- rest of Facelets code... -->

<h:panelGrid id="gtidWrapper" layout="block">
    <p:panel id="gtid"
        rendered="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.visibleGTFlag}"
        toggleable="true">
        <p:fileUpload
            fileUploadListener="#{tweetDistributionManagedBean.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced" multiple="true" update="messages" auto="true"
            sizeLimit="1048576" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf)$/" />
    </p:panel>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Oh Yes thanks I missed that point if   rendered false on page loading it not added in dom tree it will not rendered any how ...Thanks to remind me..Only one question how get values like which checkbox clicked so that i can write some business login?

Comment: I think it would work `public void renderUploadPanel(SelectEvent event) {
    String selecteValues = (String) event.getObject();}`

Comment: @user3696143 check the value of the field bounded to your checkbox in the server side. I guess you should post another question which gives a better explanation on what you want/need.